# Depend on multiple configurations from the same dependency

Tags: gradle, gradle-plugin, gradle-dependencies

I'm developing a gradle plugin that adds 3 configurations. `one`, `two`, and `three`

When I use this plugin I can add dependencies to these configurations and the plugin then used those dependencies in a certain way depending on the configuration. This works great in a single project, however if in a multi-project build I'm forced to add the following to get the dependencies from my dependent projects:

```
dependencies {
    one project(path: ':projectA', configuration: 'one')
    two project( path: ':projectA', configuration: 'two')
    three project( path: ':projectA', configuration: 'three')
}
```

Is there a way to make is so that when I declare a dependency on my other project it automatically pulls in my three custom configurations: `one`, `two`, and `three`

In my plugin I create a task that uses the different configurations:

```
project.getTasks().create("my-task", MyTask.class, t -> {
    t.getOnes().setFrom(
        project.getConfigurations().getByName("one"));
    t.getTwos().setFrom(
        project.getConfigurations().getByName("two"));
    t.getThrees().setFrom(
        project.getConfigurations().getByName("three"));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the method `DomainObjectCollection.whenObjectAdded` can help you.
Find the docs here:
https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/DomainObjectCollection.html

You could try to get a `DependencySet` from all configurations of your project, which is a `DomainObjectCollection`, and call `whenObjectAdded` on it, and then check if what is being added is your "projectA", and then do your thing.

Alternatively, you could use `project.afterEvaluate` and then search through all the dependencies at that point in time.

The same problem in both cases is to get a collection of all the dependencies, and inspect them.

Something like this could work:

```
configurations.all().each {
    if (it.allDependencies.contains(project(path: ':projectA'))) {
        // do something
    }
}
```